# include and include_once in PHP

Tags: php, include

Could someone please explain to me on when should one use the `include` and `include_once` and how should one be using it.

I am new to PHP and would like to understand this is laymans terms. Not too clear with whats mentioned on PHP documentation at [php.net](https://www.php.net).

Let us say I have the following folder structure

> -->Root-->API-->User.php
>
> -->Root-->Users-->CreateUser.php

If I have to use the `User.php` in `CreateUser.php` how should I be doing it.

And if there is another file under

> -->Root-->API-->Utility-->ImageProcessor.php

How should i being including `ImageProcessor.php` with `CreateUser.php`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you always `include_once` everything will be ok. It prevents including the same file twice.

Let's say you have these files:

`c`: `include b; include a;`

`b`: `include a;`

`a`: `echo "hello";`

when you execute `c`, `a` will be included twice (most probably an unwanted situation), therefore if you use all of them as `include_once` it will be called only once.

It comes with a little performance cost however if you are not Facebook or so, that is not a significant cost.

Comment: This seems to answer the questions perfectly, but I wanted to note that @AllisonC makes a good point that this is probably a place for require/_once rather than include/_once.  Of course the require has an additional overhead over include, but again that probably won't be significant to you.

Comment: I was thinking that require was an alias for include.

Comment: actually require will fatal error if the file is not found while include will send a warning.

Answer (score 4):

In `CreateUser.php`:

```
<pre><code>
include_once("/API/User.php");
include_once("/API/Utility/ImageProcessor.php");
</pre></code>
```

If it is necessary to make sure these files are included, you should use `require_once` instead.

Comment: Does the / before the API always refers to the include_path?

Comment: It refers to the root directory

Comment: Sounds Perfect to me.... But I see helper classes written to enhance the performance of include_once. Will this really improve performance. http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=271&thread=99835

Comment: I just did a small test, used include_once() and require_once() versus that wrapper function. In-built functions won by 5-10%. I assume it was different in 2005. Wasn't programming in php then so can't tell.

Comment: quick question, what is the difference in using include_once "file.php" and include_once("file.php")

Answer (score 4):

Use `include_once` when there's a implicitly nested requirement (any better term?) involved. I mean something like this:

Assume

- A is a department model
- B is a employee model
- C is a database module

Because model needs database connection, A and B both `includes` C. A department consists of employees working there, so A `includes` B. With `include_once`, the database module would only be included just once, so there won't be any duplicate declaration error.

`Include` is for something more general like a template of output (perhaps echoing active username) that is intentionally designed to appear multiple times.

Answer (score 4):

I'll use simple examples, one for situation when `include()` is better, one when `include_once()` is better.

Let's say you have files `a.php` and `b.php` . Each of them "includes" `library.php` which contains function `foo()`.
Now, if you try to `include` both `a.php` and `b.php` in another file, `index.php`, for example, you could get an error saying that `foo()` was already declared. Which means `include_once()` is better suited in this situation. You'll avoid defining the same function twice.

Second case. Let's assume you want to `include` `file.php` every time your loop runs.
Content of `file.php` could be just simple HTML output.

`file.php`:

```
<?php echo "User No: " . $i; ?>
```

`index.php`:

```
<?
for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){
include("file.php");
}
```

In this case, `include()` is better because it will include the file every time the loop runs. `Include_once()` would only work the first time.

Answer (score 1):

The `include_once()` statement includes and evaluates the specified file during the execution of the script. This is a behavior similar to the `include()` statement, with the only difference being that if the code from a file has already been included, it will not be included again. As the name suggests, it will be included just once.  Lets say for example, i have three files,

FILES:

1. `FUNCTIONS.PHP`
2. `GLOBALS.PHP`
3. `HEADER.PHP`

This is how each file looks like:

`FUNCTIONS.PHP`:

```
<?php 
function foo(){ 
 echo 'some code'; 
} 
?>
```

`GLOBALS.PHP`:

```
<?php 
 include('FUNCTIONS.PHP'); 
 foo(); 
?>
```

`HEADER.PHP`:

```
<?php 
 include('FUNCTIONS.PHP'); 
 include('GLOBALS.PHP'); 
 foo();
?>
```

Now if you try to open `HEADER.PHP` you will get an error because `GLOBALS.PHP` includes `FUNCTIONS.PHP` already. You will get an error saying that function `foo()` was already declared in `GLOBALS.PHP`, and I also included in `HEADER.PHP` - which means I have included `FUNCTIONS.PHP` two times.
So to be sure I only include `FUNCTIONS.PHP` only ONE time, I should use the `include_once()` `function`, so my `HEADER.PHP` should look like this:
`HEADER.PHP`:

```
<?php 
 include_once('FUNCTIONS.PHP'); 
 include('GLOBALS.PHP'); 
?>
```

Now when I open `HEADER.PHP`, I will not get an error anymore because PHP knows to `include` the file `FUNCTIONS.PHP` only ONCE
So to avoid getting an error, it would just be safe to use `include_once()` instead of `include()` function in your PHP code.